# Selecting Duplicates Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I am attempting to identify duplicate email addresses. Each email address has a unique ID and I want to identify the ID to keep (primary) based on multiple criteria. I built the query below but it is not yielding the desired results. Ideally, I would like to identify duplicate email addresses, the primary ID based on the below criteria (in order of importance), and list out duplicates along with relevant details. If duplicates tie at one priority stage the query should move to the next priority stage and so on to determine how to define the primary from secondary IDs. There may be multiple secondary IDs so the primary ID must be re-stated on each row there is a secondary ID.

- Status (prioritizing certain statuses over others)
- Last Contact Date (choose max date, if no duplicates have a Last Contact Date then move to next priority)
- Last Activity Date (choose max date, if no duplicates have a Last Contact Date then move to next priority)
- Contact Type (prioritizing certain statuses over others)
- Entry Date (prioritize in desc order)

While I am able to generate the list of duplicate email addresses it seems the logic behind defining which is the primary ID is incorrect.

```html
select 
 primary.email as primaryEmail,
 primary.id as primaryID, 
 primary.entrydate as primaryentrydate,
 primary.lastcontactdate as primarylastcontactdate,
 primary.lastactivitydate as primarylastactivitydate,
 primary.status as primarystatus,
 primary.contacttype as primarycontacttype,
    secondary.id as secondaryID, 
    secondary.entrydate as secondaryentrydate,
    secondary.lastcontactdate as secondarylastcontactdate,
    secondary.lastactivitydate as secondarylastactivitydate,
 secondary.status as secondarystatus,
 secondary.contacttype as secondarycontacttype
from (
    select 
     x.email, 
     x.entrydate,
     x.id,
     x.lastcontactdate,
     x.lastactivitydate,
     x.status,
     x.contacttype
    from 
     mytable x
    join (
        select
         email,
         entrydate,
         lastcontactdate,
         lastactivitydate,
         status,
         contacttype,
         row_number() over (partition by email
     order by (case
    when status IN ('Urgent') then 1
    when status IN ('High') then 2
    when status IN ('Medium','Medium-Low') then 3
    when status IN ('Low','Low-Low') then 4
    when status IN ('') then 5
    else 6 end),
       coalesce(max(lastcontactdate),lastcontactdate),
 coalesce(max(lastactivitydate),lastactivitydate),
    (case
    when contacttype IN ('Contacted','contacted','CONTACTED') then 1
    when contacttype IN ('Incorrect Information') then 2
    when contacttype IN ('NOT CONTACTED','Not Contacted','not contacted') then 3
    when contacttype IN ('Tried','tried','TRIED') then 4
    else 5 end),
    entrydate desc)
   from
    mytable
   group by 
    email,
    status,
    lastcontactdate,
    lastactivitydate,
    contacttype,
    entrydate
    ) y on x.email = y.email and x.lastcontactdate = y.lastcontactdate
) primary
join (
    select 
     x.email, 
     x.id, 
     x.entrydate,
     x.lastactivitydate,
     x.status,
     x.lastcontactdate,
     x.contacttype
    from 
     mytable x
    join (
        select 
         email
        from 
         mytable
        group by 
         email
        having count(*) > 1
    ) y on x.email = y.email
) secondary on primary.email = secondary.email and primary.id <> secondary.id and primary.email is not null
```

Comment: Please add a table structure, some sample data and the intended result to your question. Plus: what does `mytable` represent? contacts? events ? status changes ?

Comment: mytable contains contact information. I cannot provide sample data, unfortunately. the table should contain the 13 columns listed in the first SELECT--each row should represent a duplicate email address. The intended result to my question should be (1) identifying duplicate email addresses, (2) defining a primary email address using the prioritization listed above, (3) listing out all of the associated duplicates along with their details per the 13 columns.

Comment: Well: you can add **fake** data (and fake results) to your question. Otherwise we would have to do that for you.

Comment: This is an example http://screencast.com/t/IFVfftLwY

Comment: Does that screenshot help?

Comment: Can you provide an http://sqlfiddle.com/ link to work on ?